# MySQL query with conditional statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query left joining two tables. This is the current query result:

```
id | login | privacy-weight | requires
--------------------------------------------
0  | user  | 1              | NULL
0  | user2 | 1              | NULL
0  | user3 | 1              | privacy-weight
```

The query itself is not important, as I'd only like to add a `WHERE` condition to the query as it is now.

I need to fetch only values which (in my own words):

```
IF (`requires` = 'privacy-weight'), then `privacy-weight` must equal = 0;
```

That means, I need this condition:

```
WHERE `privacy-weight` = 0
```

BUT only if this is true:

```
requires = 'privacy-weight'
```

Can this be done?

**EDIT**

Obviously this is too difficult to understand, therefore, an example output:

```
privacy-weight | requires
-------------------------
0              | NULL
1              | NULL
0              | privacy-weight
1              | NULL
```

These would be ignored (not fetched):

```
privacy-weight | requires
-------------------------
1              | privacy-weight
```

Comment: And if `requires <> 'privacy-weight'` what do you expect?

Comment: @Muatik: no, I didn't. that's not the condition I described.

Comment: what's the point having `privacy-weight` column then as it's basically based on `requires` column ?

Comment: This question confuses WHERE clauses and IF statements which are too very different things. What rows do you actually want to output?

Comment: @Cfreak: I will edit my question.

Comment: @RiMMER This is still not clear. I have serious trouble understanding what you're after. You wrote you'd need `WHERE `privacy-weight` = 0
BUT only if this is true:
requires = 'privacy-weight'` This would simply be `WHERE privacy-weight = 0 AND requires='privacy-weight'`. Your example output however, why is there a row with privacy-weight = 1 and requires is null. Please show an excerpt of table data and the expected result, not what would be ignored.

Comment: @tombom: can we start a chat?

Comment: Sure,but I don't have that much time. And I don't know how that works. Give me a link...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql

Comment: Via your edit, my solution outputs exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this simple test:

```
WHERE (requires = 'privacy-weight' AND privacy-weight = 0) OR requires <> 'privacy-weight' OR requires IS NULL
```

The first part `(requires = 'privacy-weight' AND privacy-weight = 0)` prevents the output of:

```
privacy-weight | requires
-------------------------
1              | privacy-weight
```

But keeps:

```
privacy-weight | requires
-------------------------
0              | privacy-weight
```

While the second part `OR requires <> 'privacy-weight' OR requires IS NULL` will keep the following ones:

```
privacy-weight | requires
-------------------------
0              | NULL
1              | NULL
1              | NULL
```

Comment: Although not very sophisticated, I think this is the only solution, unfortunately. Accepting for being correct, yielding proper results.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT id, login, ( IF(requires='privacy-weight',0,privacy-weight) ) AS privacy-weight, requires
FROM [mytable]
WHERE [mywhereclause]
```

For more information on how the IF function works in MySQL see the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants. That will still output the rows where the requires is some other value

Comment: Then he can limit within his where clause. This actually outputs 0 into the column based on the value of another column, which is what he asked for. In my opinion this is more flexible for future reuse of the query.

Comment: All he needs to do is limit it in his where clause. There's no reason for an if() statement at all

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE CASE WHEN requires = 'privacy-weight' THEN 0 ELSE privacy-weight END = 0
```

Comment: Any explanation of those ZEROes, please?

Comment: This still outputs the rows that he doesn't want.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to return values when `privacy-weight` is ``NULL``

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
WHERE NOT (requires='privacy-weight' AND privacy-weight<>0)
```

Comment: Try to add an explanation instead of just 'simply'... Why does this solve the problem and in what way.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `IF()` function in mysql as @philwinkle posted but it changes the values of the columns, it doesn't affect the rows. You want to add this to your WHERE statement.

```
SELECT id, login, `privacy-weight`, requires FROM yourtable 
  WHERE `privacy-weight`=0 AND requires='privacy-weight'
```

**Edit** I've changed this back to answer the OP's question as written.

Comment: +1 if the intent is to limit the query only to privacy-weights.

Comment: Uhm, but I also want values where `requires` is ``NULL``. This ignores those.

Comment: Then you should specify that in your question. I've edited the query to account for null

Comment: Still wrong. I want values where `privacy-weight` is ``2``. The new query ignores those.

Comment: Then your question is wrong. You specifically state you want rows where privacy-weight=0 when requires='privacy-weight'

Comment: I state I want rows where privacy-weight=0 ONLY IF requires=privacy-weight.

Comment: Which is what the where condition I provided does. Based on your comments you want all rows ... and IF privacy-weight=0 it must have requires=privacy-weight set.

Comment: @Cfreak - based on OP edit, my query provides what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

You can do if condition in where clause

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE IF(requires = 'privacy-weight',privacy-weight = 0,1);
```

But you can achieve it without if too as you have mentioned you ONLY need

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE requires = 'privacy-weight'
    AND privacy - weight = 0;
```