# using CASE in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

simplified version of my query

```
SELECT *
FROM logs 
WHERE pw='correct' AND CASE WHEN id<800 THEN success=1 ELSE END 
AND YEAR(timestamp)=2011
```

this doesn't work. What i'm trying to do is to add in `success=1` only for rows with `id<800`, else ignore this check.

how do i write this? thanks!

edit: to clarify, this what the table looks like

```
|id  | pw      | success |
--------------------------
|700 | correct | 1       |
|710 | correct | 1       |
|900 | correct | NULL    |
|999 | correct | 0       |
```

I'm trying to return all the rows, the column `pw` cannot be ignored.

Comment: Maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608245/mysql-query-with-conditional-statement

Comment: Can you add your desired result also?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You don't have to use CASE...WHEN, you could use an OR condition, like this:

```
WHERE
  pw='correct'
  AND (id>=800 OR success=1) 
  AND YEAR(timestamp)=2011
```

this means that if id<800, success has to be 1 for the condition to be evaluated as true. Otherwise, it will be true anyway.

It is less common, however you could still use CASE WHEN, like this:

```
WHERE
  pw='correct'
  AND CASE WHEN id<800 THEN success=1 ELSE TRUE END 
  AND YEAR(timestamp)=2011
```

this means: return `success=1` (which can be TRUE or FALSE) in case id<800, or always return TRUE otherwise.

Comment: I love how simple yet elegant using the OR statement can be in this case.

Answer (score 36):

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE pw='correct'
  AND CASE
          WHEN id<800 THEN success=1
          ELSE 1=1
      END
  AND YEAR(TIMESTAMP)=2011
```

Comment: Upvoted because the aligment and indentation make the code more understandable.

Comment: `CASE` is the way!

Comment: ELSE 1=1 is important! :)

Answer (score 25):

This is working Oracle example but it should work in MySQL too.

You are missing smth - see IN after END Replace 'IN' with '=' sign for a single value.

```
SELECT empno, ename, job
  FROM scott.emp
 WHERE (CASE WHEN job = 'MANAGER' THEN '1'  
         WHEN job = 'CLERK'   THEN '2' 
         ELSE '0'  END) IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can transform logical implication `A => B` to `NOT A or B`. This is one of the most basic laws of logic. In your case it is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs 
WHERE pw='correct' AND (id>=800 OR success=1)  
AND YEAR(timestamp)=2011
```

I also transformed `NOT id<800` to `id>=800`, which is also pretty basic.