# IF/WHEN Statements in SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to declare variables and calculate fields in MySQL Workbench with a specific data set.  Here's an example of the data I'm pulling:

```
select
product.id as "Product ID",
product.name as "Product Name",
product.type as "Product Type",
product.weight as "Product Weight",
product.amount as "Product Amount",
product.cost as "Product Cost"
```

I have all of the appropriate joins below, but I'd like to create an additional variable that I can use to manipulate, and in this instance, declare it as "Total Cost".  Total Cost however would be different based on the "Product Type".  So if the Product Type was "variable", I would calculate the total cost as product (product.cost * product.weight), and if the Product Type was "fixed", I was calculate the total cost as (product.cost * product.amount).

Let me know if there's a way to build an IF function and declare it as a valueable before my joins.

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: I believe this is achievable with a WHERE statement, vs an IF, see this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608245/mysql-query-with-conditional-statement) for pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you add in the `WHERE` clause will also filter the amount of rows. So that is clearly not the way to go. If you just want to get an additional value that will be calculated and depending on other fields that you should use a `CASE` statement.

```
select blah, blah, blah,
    case product.type
        when 'variable' then product.cost * product.weight
        when 'fixed' then product.cost * product.amount
    end TotalCost
from blah blah
```

More information in this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

Comment: The actually created a syntax error on the end Case (Case is underlined red in MySQL Workbench).  Do I need to declare a variable for TotalCost somewhere first?

Comment: @Jeff My bad. Check the answer again. Remove the last `case`. Also updated the link.

Comment: it worked when I put end as "Total Cost".  When I put it as just TotalCost, and tried to use that as a variable I couldn't link it in the below statement.  

(TotalCost * order.quantity) as "Overall Cost"

Or something along those lines.